# How to analyze image in gjs/gnome-extensions?

Tags: image-processing, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

How I can get pixel of image in gjs/gnome-extensions? I tried `Image()` but it undefined in system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf` for this. The [`get_pixels()`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/gdkpixbuf20%7E2.42.6/gdkpixbuf.pixbuf) method will return a `Uint8Array` with the image data, and you can index an individual pixel with `pixels[y * pixbuf.rowstride + x * pixbuf.nChannels]`.

(`Image` is part of the HTML DOM. GNOME extensions don't run in a browser environment, so there's no DOM, just the same as in Node.js.)